# How to program to accept DTMF tone as input (IVR Automation)

Tags: automation, ivr, regression-testing, vxml, voxeo

I am looking to automate IVR Regression testing using Voxeo Prophecy.
the challenge I am running into is how to simulate DTMF input collection.

I have been able to build a CCXML application in Voxeo Prophecy that invokes my VXML application. I am invoking this CCXML application using Voxeo SIP phone.
Now the issue is that when my VXML application is invoked it plays the prompt "Please enter your card number" and then waits for input and finally max timeout.

I have the DTMF tones from Voxeo now I need to find where exactly I need to play these DTMF tones in order to simulate caller input. Will it be in the VXML or CCXML file?

If it is VXML then in which part of form. Any sample code will be great.
Note that I want to do minimal editing to my VXML files for automation and would prefer if it can be done by playing the DTMF tones for input elsewhere.

```
<form>
    <field name="cardNumber" type="digits">                     
                <grammar srcexpr="'/GrammarEnterCard.grxml'" type="application/srgs+xml"/>      
                    <audio expr="Eng3">  Please enter your 16 digit card number and then press the pound key.  Or press star to report your card lost or stolen.                </audio>  
                </prompt>     
                <filled>
                    <log expr="'*****In Card Number Filled*****'"/> 
                    <goto nextitem="expDate"/>          
                </filled>  
                <noinput>               

                </noinput>
                <nomatch>

                </nomatch>

    </field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created one IVR Regression testing tool for client. In this i have two IVR ( inbound and outbound). Inbound one which we are testing and outbound when is performing the testing. The dtmf and voice input are given by wave file from outbound call to inbound call( which takes it as input).

From above VXML code, i see you have created a IVR and wanted to pass/play the DTMF tone audio file to your testing IVR. The VXML which is making outbound call will be playing it.

Comment: Thanks Rajiv. How does the outbound application know when to play the DTMF input? The inbound application will be playing a host of message like the welcome prompt & the outbound application needs to stay silent during such messages.

Comment: I have handled it in two ways. 1. Enable the bargein for all prompt and give DTMF input to move to next prompt after 1 sec. 2. As you said wait for whole prompt to play. To know how long to wait, calculate the number of word count + Talent/Voice record speed per word( if you have used professional studio help they will provide you this details). Hope this helps